# GridView getting cleared on back button pressed(While keyboard is visible)

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask, textwatcher, endlessscroll

The actual problem is, i load a grid from server, i have a search field at the top of the page,after searching suppose a list is shown, i have the keyboard present in the screen, but on clicking the back button yo hide the keyboard the whole view(GridView) is getting cleared.

Here is the code

```
public class ViewClass extends Fragment {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    }


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewclass, container, false);

        mylist = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        endlessScrollListener = new EndlessScrollListener();
        mylist.setOnScrollListener(endlessScrollListener);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity());
        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
        searchflag = 0;
        _data.clear();
        index = 0;
        dialogflag = 0;
        callviewData(index, "");
        search = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.search);

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            private int length_pre;

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                System.out.println("count :" + s.length() + " length_pre:"
                        + length_pre);

                if (s.length() == 0 && length_pre == 1) {

                    endlessScrollListener.clear();

                    searchflag = 1;

                    index = 0;
                    dialogflag = 0;



                    callviewData(index, s.toString());
                } else if (s.length() > 0) {

                    endlessScrollListener.clear();
                                        searchflag = 1;

                    index = 0;
                    dialogflag = 0;




                    callviewData(index, s.toString());
                }
                length_pre = s.length();

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

this is the endless scroll listener

public class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

```
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        visibleThreshold = 5;
        currentPage = 0;
        previousTotal = 0;
        loading = true;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (loading) {
            System.out.println("httscrollllllloadingg");
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }
            System.out.println("htvvv:"
                    + (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) + "::"
                    + (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold));
        }
        if (!loading
                && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
            // but you can call any function here.
            System.out.println("httscrollllll");
            index = index + 1;
            appPref.SaveData(String.valueOf(index), "index");
            dialogflag = 1;



            callviewData(index, search.getText().toString());
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This is the custom adapter

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

            Context context;
            private Filter planetFilter;
            ArrayList<RowItem> rowItems;

            public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
                rowItems = _data;
                // this.rowItems = rowItems;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                System.out.println("list data:" + _data.size());
                return _data.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {

                return position;
            }

            /* private view holder class */
            private class ViewHolder {
                ImageView pic;
                TextView title;
                TextView desc;
                LinearLayout rl;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder = null;

                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_holder, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();

                    holder.rl = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl);
                    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tName);
                    holder.pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iItem);

                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    // convertView.setTag(holder);
                }

                try {

                    imgj = _data.get(position).getPro_pic().toString();

                    if (imgj.equals("")) {
                        imgj = "no_photo.png";
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    imageLoader.displayImage(upurl + imgj.replace(" ", "%20"),
                            holder.pic, doption_two, animateFirstListener);

                    holder.title.setText(_data.get(position).getTitle());

                    System.out.println("list position pid:"
                            + _data.get(position).getPid());

                    holder.rl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                // int pos =
                                // Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                                System.out.println("list position pid:"
                                        + _data.get(position).getPid());
                                appPref.SaveData(_data.get(position).getPid(),
                                        "pdet_id");
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                search.setText("");


                                appPref.SaveData(String.valueOf(position),
                                        "sel_pos");
                                addFragment.addFragment(new DetailView(), true,
                                        FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_NONE,
                                        "detview", R.id.tabContent, getActivity());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return convertView;
            }

 }      }
```

This is the asynctask to populate data

```
public void callviewData(final int ind, final String value) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            String result = "";

            ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (searchflag == 1) {
                    _data.clear();
                }
                if (dialogflag == 0) {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading , Please wait...");
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String url = "http://dummy.com/json/product_view.php?index="
                        + ind + "&value=" + value;
                System.out.println("url---" + url);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jpass.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                    result = jsonObject.getString("result");
                    if (result.equals("success")) {
                        JSONArray Details = jsonObject.getJSONArray("details");

                        for (int i = 0; i <= Details.length() - 1; i++) {
                            RowItem row = new RowItem();
                            JSONObject detail = Details.getJSONObject(i);

                            row.setTitle(detail.getString("title"));
                            row.setDesc(detail.getString("description"));
                            row.setPro_pic(detail.optString("image", "c"));
                            row.setPid(detail.getString("p_id"));

                            _data.add(row);

                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    dialogflag = 0;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void arg) {
                try {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("exception post execute");
                    if (dialogflag == 0) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    if (result.equals("success")) {
                        System.out.println("sixe is " + _data.size());
                        appPref.SaveData(String.valueOf(_data.size()), "siz");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }

                    super.onPostExecute(arg);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have created the adapter class in the same fragment.
Instead of calling `adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), _data);`
in the oncreate view try initializing it inside the onPostexecute were you call your server 
hope this will solve your issue